# Anylogic - create Resources and add to ResourcePool

Tags: resources, simulation, anylogic

I'm having difficulty finding the documentation I need to work with Resources and resourcePools - there is no "resource API documentation" that I can find.

I would like to programatically create static resources (of a custom type) and then add these resources to a resourcePool.  When creating the resources, I'd like to be able to specify their property values prior to adding them to the resourcePool.  In my mind the code would look something like this:

```
Room myRoom;
myRoom = new Room("redRoom", 20);
addTo_myResourcePool(myRoom);

myRoom = new Room("greenRoom", 10);
addTo_myResourcePool(myRoom);
```

Does anyone know if there are ways to achieve this end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a blind spot in AnyLogic. It can only be done indirectly:

1. Create an empty agent population with your agent type
2. Tell the resource pool to use that agent type
3. set the resource pool capacity as you need. The pool will create agents for your in that population (if the capacity is larger than the current number of resources)

If you want to manually create a resource, you must call `myResourcePool.set_Capacity(myResourcePool.getCapacity()+1)`

Destroying 1 resource works vice-versa.

Also, make sure to "destroy resources on capacity decrease" so the agents are destroyed from the population

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, that is great advice yet again.  I'll work with that but leave the question open for a bit longer to give others the opportunity to contribute.

Comment: @CrustyNoodle you can also parameterize the agent that gets created by programmatically creating a new agent in the `New resource Unit:` section in the resource pool parameters. This is one of the few places where you can programmatically create agens using `new myAgent()` and use them inside a flow chart.

Comment: @Jaco-BenVosloo The "On new unit" action of a resource pool allows you to configure the *just created* resource unit (not create one). That's what the OP will need to give his new resource units custom parameter values.

Comment: Note also that often you aren't explicitly (programmatically) creating new agents via `set_Capacity`. (You're, say, creating them implicitly via a Schedule.) You can still then parametrise the newly-created resource unit via the "On new unit" action.

Comment: But there are various issues/limitations with how resource pools work (as Ben hints at) that limit what you are able to do in terms of 'controlling' a set of resource units with diverse attributes; in *some* cases it is better/necessary to not use resource pools at all and effectively write your own seize/release logic (including for things like end-of-shift) though that has its own set of problems of course (such as not 'linking in' to things like priorities and pre-emption).

Comment: "in some cases it is better/necessary to not use resource pools at all" -> unfortunately, this is true.

Comment: That is true but based on the code example new Room("redRoom", 20); the OP already has a resource type agent with two parameters that can easily be used.

Comment: @StuartRossiter I can see that Jaco's solution uses the "New resource unit:" parameter field not the "On new unit:" parameter field so I believe his suggest will work to enable paramaterisation of the new resource unit on creation.  However, I don't believe there will be a clean way to pass those parameters to the ResourcePool when you want to create and add new resources.

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on the newUnit() method of the ResourcePool class?  On face value it appears that it would be perfect for adding units to the pool while allowing you to configure those resources on creation (as it returns a new resource for the pool).  However, when I use this method the available resources in the pool does not increase so it is like it creates a resource but doesn't add it to the pool...

Comment: @CrustyNoodle I have added an answer using my method of using the "new resource unit" I think this is a lot closer to what you wanted. Let us know what works and what does not ;-)

Comment: @CrustyNoodle I've clarified what I mean (and how it relates to answers from Ben and Jaco) in a new answer that tries to bring everything together.

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick I use for this, that works sometimes, but I wouldn't generalize it as a final solution...I only do it when i have a few different unit characteristics, which seems to be your case.

step 1: create a population of resourcePools... each resource pool will correspond to one kind of agent characteristics, and all resourcePools use the same resource (agent) type
[image: resourcePool advanced]

step 2: in the on new unit of the resource pool, you will use the index of the resourcePool population to generate the unit with particular characteristics... then you can just do something like resourcePool.get(i).set_capacity(whatever) in order to generate a resource unit with the exact characteristics you want

step 3: when you seize the resource, you will use alternatives... each resourcePool from the resourcePool population will be 1 option among the alternatives to use... you will need to create a function that retourns a ResourcePool[][]

step 4: you will use conditions to select the unit based on its characteristics (customize resource selection)

Comment: Thanks Felipe, that is a very succinct method for creating large numbers of resource groups.  It is close to what I require in this instance but I will accept Ben's answer as it is a bit closer to the root of the solution and should help others along the way as well.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a population of your resource agent, which I assume is of type room based on your code.

Then you have a function that will add a new agent to the population and return it to the caller.

[image]

And now you only need to add this to the `new resource unit` call in the resource pool object

[image]

Do not change the "Add Units to" option since we are already doing this in the function.

I tested this in a small model by having two buttons to increase and decrease the capacity during execution using

`resourcePool.set_capacity(max(0, resourcePool.size() + 1));`
and

```
remove_myResource(myResource.get(myResource.size()-1));
resourcePool.set_capacity(max(0, myResource.size()));
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Jaco, this sounds like a very suitable solution for my use case.  I will have a shot at implementing it now.

Comment: Thanks again Jaco, this method works but it is a bit messy when trying to pass the individual unit parameters to the getNewRoom() method.  The solution I have implemented first sets the ResourcePool capacity and places the new units into a custom population.  Then I iterate through the custom population to set the parameters of each of the units.  I only need to do this once at the start of a run. Not a particularly elegant solution but it works.  I'll continue to see if I can get a clean implementation of your solution.

Comment: I'd be very weary removing a resource from the population then reducing the size of the resourcePool - there is no guarantee that the agent you removed from the population and the resource unit the resourcePool removed are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several related points here.

- AnyLogic is designed such that you only change the agents in a resource pool via changing the capacity of the pool. This can be done *directly* via the pool's `set_capacity` function (if the pool's capacity is set to be defined "Directly"), but is more commonly done *indirectly* by linking the pool's capacity to a schedule (to represent shift patterns or any other pre-defined changes over time in capacity).

  Resource pools will keep agents by default when the capacity decreases (i.e., they exist but are 'unavailable'), but you can set it to delete them. What you'll want will depend on what the resources and any resource-specific attributes/state represent.
- If you need to address/access the agents in the resource pool independently from their use as seized/released resources you would have the pool store them in a custom population (rather than put them in the default population along with all other agents not created in a custom population) via the "Add units to" setting. Then you can access that population explicitly (e.g., loop through it) whenever you need to. Otherwise this aspect is not necessary.
- If your resource pool is of custom agents with parameters (or other state that needs initialising in a particular way), the standard approach is to have direct/indirect capacity increases create the unit (with default parameter values) and then do any follow-on initialisation in the "On new unit" action (where you have access to the newly-created unit via the `agent` keyword).

  You *can* alternatively do it via a dynamic expression for the "New resource unit" (as in Jaco's answer) but this doesn't particularly gain you anything (though it's equally valid). Yes, it's a bit more 'object-oriented', but there are loads of barriers AnyLogic puts up to doing things in a proper OO way anyway — as you say, the more 'obvious' OO approach would just be to have methods on the resource pool which add/remove agents. Basically, the standard 'design pattern' on blocks which create agents, like a Resource Pool or a Source block, is to let it create them with default info and then customise it in the appropriate action.

  You could also use the "On startup" action of the resource pool agent as well / instead, but normally you would be using information from the process-containing agent to determine what state the new resource agent should have, which makes the "On startup" action less useful.

  Finally(!), if you have an unchanging set of resource pool agents and it's easier to initialise them together (e.g., because there is some database input data for all of them that can thus just be looped through once), then just do that in your "On startup" action of the agent containing the resource pool (which runs after the resource pool has initialised and created default-state agents). That *will* require them in a custom population so you can loop through just those agents. But your question seemed to imply you were concerned about *dynamic* additions of resource agents.

But, as some of my other comments indicated, there are various subtleties/restrictions in how resource pools work (really based on them currently being designed as a pool where the explicit identity of each individual is not fully 'controllable') which mean that what you actually need may go beyond this.

A couple of examples:

- If you wanted your resources to be explicit individual staff with info tracked across shifts (e.g., with their state changing to reflect experience or the history of tasks they've conducted), you have the complication that you can't control *which* resources (if you didn't delete them on capacity decrease) 'come back' when the capacity changes, so you may need more complex workarounds such as having separate resource pools for each distinct shift and seizing from resource sets including all such pools — only one of them (the active shift one) will have non-zero capacity at any given time unless the shifts overlap.
- If capacity decreases (representing end-of-shift), you can't control / determine *which* resource agents are chosen to go off-shift. Plus there are issues regarding resource agents which are still active finishing a task before they actually 'leave' (given that shift-ends weren't set to pre-empt) — because they still exist until they finish, if you increase the capacity again whilst they're working AnyLogic won't create a new resource agent (it will just add this existing agent back as an 'active' agent in the pool). So that makes some other things harder...

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that is a very complete explanation of things.  It certainly highlights some shortcomings in the resource implementation, in particular the ability to control individual resources.  Unfortunately not all resources in a resource pool are always the same so control over which resources are "decommissioned" at the end of a shift or indeed which resources are released in a release block can be critical to some use cases. 
In this instance I have gone with your "Finally(!)" solution as I am able to create all resources as a once off at the start of the simulation.